# Google maps: Calibrate position

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an application for taxis, and I have the inconvenience that the client sees my location inaccurate by seconds, and the marker moves in circles and does not stay still.

I attach my code.

```
public class TrackerService extends Service {
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};

public void onCreate() {
try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        double distance = mLastLocation.distanceTo(location);
        Log.e("distance", distance+"");
}
}
}
```

How could you optimize so that these sudden changes in position do not occur?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to implement filtering above this.  GPS is not 100% accurate.  Its accurate to only within about 10m with modern phone hardware.  Even then, each measurement comes with an accuracy score in meters and there's only a 67% chance you're within that many meters of the location it gives.

You can look into some algorithms like Kalman filters, or smoothing out changes by dropping sudden moves or slowly adding them in over a few updates.  But you're going to have to do some actual algorithm design to get it dialed in, its not a matter of not calling the right API.

Comment: Hello, I was thinking about updating my position only if there is a change of 5 to 10 meters, that is, if my current position is different 5 meters from the previous one, then send me to this position and show it to the client, currently sending the put every second. From my code, since I was able to improve that part, I got the distance that was moved using this:

double distance = mLastLocation.distanceTo(location); As I could if I moved 5 meters send those coordinates to the backed.